# How to add ost file in microsoft outlook using MAPI C#

Tags: c#, outlook, store, profile, mapi

i am trying to add a ost file in microsoft outlook using following code .

```
app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
pstFilePath=myfile.ost;
outlookNs.AddStore(pstFilePath);
```

But when my controls comes on Addstore method i am getting exception as "Unable to load data file", but same code is working fine for pst file.

Can anyone help me to reach out of this problems.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [AddStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.addstore) and [AddStoreEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.addstoreex) methods of the `Namespace` class  adds a Personal Folders (.pst) file to the current profile. You need to convert OST file into PST file format to be able to attach it to the profile using OOM.

FYI: OST files can only ne open in the profile for which they were originally configured. You cannot simply copy an OST to a different machine or open it in a different profile on the same machine. See [Outlook 2007/2010 convert .ost file into .pst using VBA](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1501b16e-0ef9-47d2-bf0c-c69a2de72a0b/outlook-20072010-convert-ost-file-into-pst-using-vba?forum=isvvba) for more information.